# Latex cant read from my .dat file

Tags: tables, pgfplots, plot, matlab, database

I wrote a .dat file from Matlab. this data has 8 columns each having 1x101 values.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots,tikz,graphicx}

\title{  Experimental Results & Plots }
\author{John doe }
\date{February 2019}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\newenvironment{customlegend}[1][]{%
    \begingroup

    \csname pgfplots@init@cleared@structures\endcsname
    \pgfplotsset{#1}%
}{%
    % draws the legend:
    \csname pgfplots@createlegend\endcsname
    \endgroup
}%

\def\addlegendimage{\csname pgfplots@addlegendimage\endcsname}
\pgfplotsset{
    cycle list={%
        {draw=black,solid,line width=2pt},
        {draw=black, dashed,line width=2pt},%densely dashed}, 
        {draw=red,solid,line width=2pt},%dashdotted}, %every mark/.append style={rotate=90},
        {draw=red, dashed,line width=2pt},
}}
\definecolor{darkgreen}{rgb}{0.125,0.5,0.169}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
    \title{  Gaussian Compressionh}
    \maketitle
 \begin{figure*}[ht]
    %\hspace{10ex}
    ~\hfill
    \resizebox{.6\textwidth}{!}{
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{customlegend}[legend columns=4,legend style={align=left,draw=none,column sep=2ex},legend entries={{AS-V},{AS-GC},{AS-GC-RE},{AS-RSI}}]
        \addlegendimage{brown, solid,line width=2pt}
        \addlegendimage{brown, dashed,line width=2pt}
        \addlegendimage{black, solid,line width=2pt}
        \addlegendimage{black, dashed,line width=2pt}

        \end{customlegend}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }\hfill ~
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

    \resizebox{0.5\textwidth}{!}{\begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{semilogyaxis}[ ticklabel style = {font=\Large} , ytick={1,1.e-2,1.e-4,1.e-6,1.e-8} , ymax=1, ymin=1.e-9 , xmin=1 , xmax=101, xlabel=\Large{iterations} , ylabel=\Large{Relative Recons. Error} , legend style={at={(0.03,0.97)},anchor=north west}]
        \addlegendimage{empty legend}\addlegendentry{\Large{ $\nu =1$}}

        \addplot[green,line width=2pt] table[x=[1:101], y=aS_V]{nu_150_pass.dat};
        \addplot[brown,line width=2pt, dashed] table[x=[1:101], y=aS_GC]{nu_150_pass.dat};
        \addplot[black,line width=2pt] table[x=[1:101], y=aS_RSI]{nu_150_pass.dat};
        \addplot[black,line width=2pt, dashed] table[x=[1:101], y=aS_GC_RE]{nu_150_pass.dat};

        \end{semilogyaxis}

 \end{tikzpicture}
}
\caption{plot of nmf }\label{fig:RRE1}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

So the y axis will pick values using the header handles from the dat file. and since each column has 101 values my x axis should go from 1 :101. But latex cant read the table. i dont know why
Matlab code that created the .dat file

```
    T=table(aS_V',aS_GC',aS_RSI',aS_GC_RE',neNMF_GC',neNMF_RSI',neNMF_GC_RE',...
neNMF_V','VariableNames','aS_V','aS_GC','aS_RSI','aS_GC_RE','neNMF_GC',...
'neNMF_RSI','neNMF_GC_RE','neNMF_V'});

namedatfile= ['nu_' int2str(nu) '_pass.dat'];
fname = namedatfile;
writetable(T,fname,'Delimiter',' ')
```

Link: to get my nu_150.dat file 
https://www.sendspace.com/file/ytu593

Comment: Error from latex: "Package pgfplots Error: Sorry, could not retrieve column 'aS_V' from table '\name aliases).. }"

Comment: Hi and welcome. Please give a fully compilable code.

Comment: how do i edit the question please

Comment: At the very bottom left of your question is the text `share edit close flag` click on `edit`.

Comment: Could you edit a small part of your data file (for example 2 columns and 5 rows) to your question in text format? Open the `nu_150_pass.dat` file in a text editor (so _not_ in a spreadsheet program like in your screenshot) and copy-paste the text from there. It would be useful to see which delimiters are used in the file, for example.

Comment: Also, it would be useful to make the code in your question much smaller, remove anything that is not related to the issue, i.e., remove all the packages except for `pgfplots` and remove the first 50 lines or so after `\begin{document}`.

Comment: Here is the link to the dat file. Its impossible to just select two columns. from a text editor. https://www.sendspace.com/file/a4elyi

Comment: The file you linked only has a header row and no data, so that is not really useful. However, it seems like the separator character is TAB, is that correct?

Comment: sorry i attached wrong file. Also please see edited question on how i created the table in matlab. updated file: Here: https://www.sendspace.com/file/ytu593

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The x coordinate can be specified with the syntax `x expr=\coordindex`, which means that the row index of the table is used as x value. Optionally you can specify `col sep=space` to make sure `pgfplots` understands the column separator in the data file.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{semilogyaxis}[
        ticklabel style = {font=\Large},
        ytick={1,1.e-2,1.e-4,1.e-6,1.e-8},
        ymax=1,
        ymin=1.e-9,
        xmin=1,
        xmax=101,
        xlabel=\Large{iterations},
        ylabel=\Large{Relative Recons. Error}
        ]
        \addplot[green,line width=2pt] table[x expr=\coordindex, y=aS_V, col sep=space]{nu_150_pass.dat};
        \addplot[brown,line width=2pt, dashed] table[x expr=\coordindex,y=aS_GC, col sep=space]{nu_150_pass.dat};
        \addplot[black,line width=2pt] table[x expr=\coordindex,y=aS_RSI, col sep=space]{nu_150_pass.dat};
        \addplot[black,line width=2pt, dashed] table[x expr=\coordindex,y=aS_GC_RE, col sep=space]{nu_150_pass.dat};
        \legend{AS-V,AS-GC,AS-GC-RE,AS-RSI}
        \end{semilogyaxis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: wow, a million thanks. Its perfect.

Comment: @FaroukYahaya If this answer solved your problem, you can upvote it by pressing the up arrow on the left of the question and/or accept it by pressing the Checkmark.